# GWT Button EventListener not fired

Tags: gwt, button

I have a `<div id="test"><input type="button" value="OK" /></div>` html tag.

I used:

```
((HasClickHandlers)RootPanel.get("test").getWidget(0)).addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.alert('sss');
  }
}
```

I executed but no action.

Update:

```
package com.example.client;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class ExampleWebApp implements EntryPoint {
  public void onModuleLoad() { 
    ((HasClickHandlers) RootPanel.get("test").getWidget(0)).addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { 
      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.alert("i got it");
      }
    });
   }
 }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <div id="test">
      <input type=button onClick="" value='click here'>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have a &lt;div id="test"&gt;&lt;input type="button" value="OK" /&gt;&lt;/div&gt; html tag.

Comment: I have a div id="test" input type="button" value="OK" in html tag. 
but no action

Comment: Simply because you cast the widget doesn't mean that you're 'magically' getting the handlers.

You must make sure that the widget you added to the Root implements properly the HasClickHandlers interface.

If you add your whole code, will help.

Comment: package com.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;



public class ExampleWebApp implements EntryPoint {

 public void onModuleLoad() {
  ((HasClickHandlers) RootPanel.get("test").getWidget(0)).addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.alert("i got it");  
     }
   });
 }
}

<table>
<tr>
  <div id="test"><input type=button onClick="" value='click here'>
  </div>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: i submitted my code pls notice my problem i did not distinguish.
is there any problem in html div tag?? can not i write directly 
<input type=button value=""/> in this fashion?? forwhich HasClickHandlers is not compatible??

Comment: Please learn to use the site properly before asking questions - there's a 'edit' button you know and using some markup would help too.. :/ About your question - you clearly misunderstood the way GWT works, please head to the official docs (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/index.html), dig through them and *then* maybe come back with sensible questions.

Answer (score 2):

The GWT Button widget is a `button` tag and not a `input` tag. Which means you can't use the GWT Button widget in this case. To make it work you need to create your own widget, which can be based on the widget `ButtonBase`, but needs to be initialized with an `InputElement` object instead of a `ButtonElement`.

The next step to get tag from html is to add something similar to the static `wrap` method present in most widgets. Here is how it would be used in your example when the `input` would have been a `button` tag:

```
Button.wrap(RootPanel.get("test").getWidget(0).getElement()).addClickHandler(
    new ClickHandler() {
       @Override public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
          Window.alert('sss');
       }
    });
```

In you case you could add a `wrap` method to your custom input widget. See the `Button` widget implementation of te `wrap` method, it's the same, expect of course for the creation of the widget itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just take an html button and try to add click handlers to it. You need to create the button using gwt code. Try:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

And then:

```
Button button = new Button("OK");
RootPanel.get("test").add(button);
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {...});
```